# How can I add a background image in a html file in dynamic web project using eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse

I am using tomcat server in eclipse and I want to add a background image in a html file. 
But I don't know how to set the path of the image. Please help me find the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set relative path from webapp as ROOT. Ensure that the image is included in build and copied to the mentioned build path.

Comment: I didn't get you properly. Could you please be more specific and clear?

Comment: Hope you are building webapp in eclipse and running the webapp using tomcat server plugin in eclipse. Then you should have WEB-INF folder in your webapp. Create a folder /images which will be sibling for /WEB-INF. Then copy your image you need to set as background image. Then you could refer the image as `~/images/bck.jpg` in html/css.

Comment: Hope you are new stackoverflow. Try to accept the answers if it really worked for you

Answer (score -1):

Also we need to use below tags along with html:

```
img src="<.jpg>" alt="<valid name" style="width:303px;height:221px;" tags to HTML page
```